# groovyPagesTemplateEngine failing in quartz job with error

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler, template-engine

We are using Quartz scheduling in our application to schedule jobs to generate and send self-audit emails.
I am trying to generate the processed emailBody from the email Template using GroovyPagesTemplateEngine. 
The emailTemplate is processed properly into EmailBody when the processing does not use Quartz scheduling. But when a job is run using Quartz for emailtemplate processing the

```
groovyPagesTemplateEngine is failing in quartz job with error
[12:10:55 AM] Mandar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: TemplateEngine not initialised correctly, no [resourceLoader] specified!
```

this what I am trying to do

```
def getInfo(){
MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest()


    GrailsWebRequest grailsWebRequest = new GrailsWebRequest(servletRequest, new MockHttpServletResponse(), new MockServletContext())
    grailsWebRequest.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.WEB_REQUEST, grailsWebRequest, 0)
    RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes = grailsWebRequest

    GroovyPagesTemplateEngine engine = new GroovyPagesTemplateEngine()

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)

    engine.createTemplate('myteplate').make(model).writeTo(pw)
    println sw.toString()
    return sw.toString()
}
```

I am aware that the Quartz scheduler does not have a WebRequest associated with it. and I am thinking that the email processing is failing due to this.
How can I process the emailtemplate to generate the emailBody content when the scheduled job is run, and not by logging into the application from UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The resourceLoader is not initialized in the groovyPagesTemplateEngine as you are just creating a new instance of it directly. Instead, you should let Spring's dependency injection do the job for you.

Add the following line to your service:

```
class YourService {

    def groovyPagesTemplateEngine

    def getInfo(){
      GroovyPagesTemplateEngine engine = groovyPagesTemplateEngine
      //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the steps mentioned in http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/12/27/request-mocking-to-use-groovypagestemplateengine-in-backend-threads/

If you are on Grails 2.0.x, you get a bean named groovyPageRenderer, which can be used outside the context of a web request as well. For more details, http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html